# Try and Catch using Integer.parseInt() syntax error [Java]

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to make a simple method which test to see if a provide String contains only numbers, to do this I am trying to use try and catch (just learnt it and I would like to practise putting it to use) where I try to parseInt() the given String and if there's an error (not a number) then it will catch it and return false;

```
    public boolean checkNumber(String s){
    try(Integer.parseInt(s)){
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception E){
        return false;
    }
}
```

It says I have a misplaced constructor.

Comment: You actually should be using regex expressions... But that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: To elaborate on skiwis comment, a string representation of a number falling ouside the range of an integer will throw an exception when parsed by `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: The syntax you are using is for "try with resources". You might want to look it up, can be useful in other circumstances.

Comment: @Khaelid On everything that is not a number, an `Exception` will be thrown and caught, which are generally a big order of magnitude slower than simple checks. Exceptions are for **exceptional** situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch the correct exception and move the try check into the block rather than in brackets.

```
 try {
       Integer.parseInt(s);
       return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is true but it'd be defensive programming to enforce a null check, it could be expected for a NPE to throw if `s` is passed in as null as just blindly checking for it could hide other errors.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct syntax for try. Use

```
try
{
    Integer.parseInt(s);
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

syntax error

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch(Exception e) {
  return false;
}
return true;
```